# MySQL query with sub query GROUP BY and MAX

Tags: mysql

( updated the question to be more clear what to expect)

**Tables**

Main table

[image]

table on left join

[image]

***The query***

```
SELECT m.id           AS id,
       m.receiverId   AS receiverId,
       m.creationDate AS creationDate,
       m.status       AS status,
       m.tokens       AS tokens,
       mm.carrier     AS carrier,
       mm.fromNumber  AS fromNumber,
       mm.keyword     AS keyword,
       mm.ref         AS ref,
       mm.message     AS message
FROM ctb_smsMessenger AS m
         LEFT JOIN ctb_smsMessengerMessage AS mm ON m.id = mm.smsMessengerId
WHERE m.status IN ("new")
```

**Result**

[image]

**Desired result**

Get records with the IDS 2, 11, 14 and 19 with the correct columns from both tables.

**Query so far**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT m.id      AS id,
             m.receiverId   AS receiverId,
             m.creationDate AS creationDate,
             m.status       AS status,
             m.tokens       AS tokens,
             mm.carrier     AS carrier,
             mm.fromNumber  AS fromNumber,
             mm.toNumber    AS toNumber,
             mm.keyword     AS keyword,
             mm.ref         AS ref,
             mm.message     AS message
      FROM ctb_smsMessenger AS m
               LEFT JOIN ctb_smsMessengerMessage AS mm ON m.id = mm.smsMessengerId
      WHERE m.status IN ("new")
      GROUP BY m.receiverId, mm.fromNumber) as m
ORDER BY m.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

**Result so far**

[image]

**Problem**

Only the ID column is displaying the correct data (ID's). The other columns are data which do not match.

**What to expect**

Each receiverID can have different and multiple numberFrom numbers.

Get all the records with the last inserted record based on the receiverId and numberFrom. ( IDS 2, 11, 14 and 19 )

Comment: Your obsession with mmm identifiers is notable 

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get all records that have the highest ID value, grouped by m.receiverId and mm.fromNumber and use IN at the WHERE IN clause.

```
SELECT m.id           AS id,
       m.receiverId   AS receiverId,
       m.creationDate AS creationDate,
       m.status       AS status,
       m.tokens       AS tokens,
       mm.carrier     AS carrier,
       mm.fromNumber  AS fromNumber,
       mm.toNumber    AS toNumber,
       mm.keyword     AS keyword,
       mm.ref         AS ref,
       mm.message     AS message
FROM ctb_smsMessenger AS m
         LEFT JOIN ctb_smsMessengerMessage AS mm ON m.id = mm.smsMessengerId
WHERE m.status IN ("new")
  AND m.id IN (SELECT MAX(m.id) AS id
               FROM ctb_smsMessenger AS m
                        LEFT JOIN ctb_smsMessengerMessage AS mm ON m.id = mm.smsMessengerId
               WHERE m.status IN ("new")
               GROUP BY m.receiverId, mm.fromNumber)
GROUP BY m.receiverId, mm.fromNumber
ORDER BY m.id ASC
```